# Is it possible to set an object to null?

Tags: c++, object, null, is-empty, stdoptional

Further in my code, I check to see check if an object is null/empty.

Is there a way to set an object to null?

Answer (score 75):

An object of a class cannot be set to NULL; however, you can set a pointer (which contains a memory address of an object) to NULL.

Example of what you can't do which you are asking:

```
Cat c;
c = NULL;//Compiling error
```

Example of what you can do:

```
Cat c;
//Set p to hold the memory address of the object c
Cat *p = &c;
//Set p to hold NULL
p = NULL;
```

Comment: as an aside for whoever wants to bring it up, yes you can overload operator= but this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: The 1st could work with `Cat::operator=(...)`. Anyway, looks like OP really wants to check a pointer. So, +1.

Comment: @jweyrich: I knew someone would say that so see my comment before your comment :)

Comment: sorry, I didn't update the page before posting my comment. It was just for the sake of completeness. Glad you mentioned :)

Comment: @wulfgarpro You don't need any includes for `nullptr`, it's a keyword.

Comment: Correct, `cstddef` is needed for hash define `NULL`, which is an implementation defined null pointer constant.

Answer (score 29):

While it is true that an object cannot be "empty/null" in C++, in C++17, we got [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to express that intent.

Example use:

```
std::optional<int> v1;      // "empty" int
std::optional<int> v2(3);   // Not empty, "contains a 3"
```

You can then check if the `optional` contains a value with

```
v1.has_value(); // false
```

or

```
if(v2) {
    // You get here if v2 is not empty
}
```

A plain `int` (or any type), however, can never be "null" or "empty"  in any useful sense. Think of `std::optional` as a container in this regard.

If you don't have a C++17 compliant compiler at hand, you can use [boost.optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) instead. Some pre-C++17 compilers also offer `std::experimental::optional`, which should behave at least close to the actual `std::optional`. Check your compiler's manual for details.

Comment: Or `std::experimental::optional` if your compiler provides that.

Answer (score 5):

You can set any pointer to `NULL`, though `NULL` is simply defined as 0 in C++:

```
myObject *foo = NULL;
```

Also note that `NULL` is defined if you include standard headers, but is not built into the language itself.  If `NULL` is undefined, you can use 0 instead, or include this:

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif
```

As an aside, if you really want to set an object, not a pointer, to `NULL`, you can read about the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Answer (score 4):

You want to check if an object is NULL/empty. Being NULL and empty are not the same. Like Justin and Brian have already mentioned, in C++ NULL is an assignment you'd *typically* associate with pointers. You can overload operator= perhaps, but think it through real well if you actually want to do this. Couple of other things:

1. In C++ NULL pointer is very different to pointer pointing to an 'empty' object.
2. Why not have a `bool IsEmpty()` method that returns true if an object's variables are reset to some default state? Guess that might bypass the NULL usage.
3. Having something like `A* p = new A; ... p = NULL;` is bad (no delete p) unless you can ensure your code will be garbage collected. If anything, this'd lead to memory leaks and with several such leaks there's good chance you'd have slow code.
4. You may want to do this `class Null {}; Null _NULL;` and then overload operator= and operator!= of other classes depending on your situation.

Perhaps you should post us some details about the context to help you better with option 4.

Arpan

Comment: "Why not have a bool IsEmpty() method ..." - there are some good reasons not to. The most important one is that it's typically contex-dependent whether it makes sense. A more robust solution is to use `boost::optional<T>` to indicate whether you have a valid T object or not. This will prevent you from calling `x.foo()` when `x.IsEmpty()==true`

Answer (score 0):

"an object" of what type?

You can certainly assign `NULL` (and `nullptr`) to objects of pointer types, and it is implementation defined if you can assign `NULL` to objects of arithmetic types.

If you mean objects of some class type, the answer is **NO** (excepting classes that have `operator=` accepting pointer or arithmetic types)

"empty" is more plausible, as many types have both copy assignment and default construction (often implicitly). To see if *an existing object* is like a default constructed one, you will also need an appropriate `bool operator==`

Answer (score -3):

yes it is possible to assign null to assign null value to a variable of any data type in many Programing languages with the NULL keyword and with the following method
int a="NULL";
here int is the datatype of the variable a and by this method NULL value is assigned to the variable a.

Comment: This question was tagged as C++, so this answer "yes" is completely wrong. The qualification "many Programing languages" fails to include the one language which matters. Also, in almost all of those languages, `"NULL"` is a string because it's quoted, and therefore distinct from a keyword `NULL`.