# Method returning an object or a NULL value

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function that returns an object (an object representing a record in a database), but if the requested data are not present in the DB, it should return a NULL value. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030829/is-it-possible-to-set-an-object-to-null) answer, is not possible to set an object NULL, but it is possible to return a pointer to the object and the pointer can be NULL. So I did it on my method, but - as the pointer is a local object - the applications does not work as expected (actually, it does work on Windows, but not in Linux). After investigating the issue, I found that [returning a pointer to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042552/returning-a-pointer-of-a-local-variable-c) is not a good idea. What is the best solution to handle my case? Using a smart pointer seems to me overcomplicated for this case.

Comment: Can you use `std::optional`?

Comment: Had you scrolled down to the second answer, you would have found the solution.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that searching `C++ return optional` would not have already resolved this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::optional` (or `boost::optional`) to represent a value that might exist or not exist without requiring any dynamic allocation.

```
std::optional<int> read_from_database(const std::string& id)
{
    return db.has(id) ? std::optional<int>{} : db.get(id); 
}
```

Comment: Btw, there is not need to repeat the type here. See [Return Optional value with ?: operator](//stackoverflow.com/a/45390238)
Not that it matters much in this simple case of course.