# Setting the Last element to NULL

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation

i have an array of object class, and i want to assign the last indexi to NULL 
i have the following code, but it gives an error

`DNA` is a class

`allRightSequences` is a vector

```
DNA* newDNA = new DNA[allRightSequences.size()];

newDNA [allRightSequences.size()] = NULL; << this line gives an error
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What is the purpose of having a "null" element at the end?

Comment: You can't set a non pointer value to `NULL`?

Comment: "gives an error" -> it would help to include the error message you get!

Comment: Recommended reading: [Is it possible to set an object to null?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3030829) Also, `newDNA [allRightSequences.size()]` is not the last element, but one beyond that.

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` is a macro that, in appropriate situations, will expand into something that can be treated as a null pointer constant. So you can use it to set a pointer value:

```
int *ip = NULL; // okay
```

However, `newDNA` does not contain pointers; it contains objects of type `DNA`. Forget the array for a moment. The problem is this:

```
DNA dna = NULL;
```

This won't work, unless `DNA` has a constructor that can be called with whatever `NULL` expands into.

If you really need to have a marker at the end of the array you need to create an array of **pointers**. But you **really** don't need this. Use `std::vector<DNA>`, which keeps track of the size for you.

Comment: Finally an answer that actually talks about the wrongness of the NULL assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`allRightSequences.size()` is not the last index of an array that has `allRightSequences.size()` elements. The last index is `allRightSequences.size() - 1`. The behaviour of accessing the array out of bounds is undefined.

Another potential problem: There must exist an appropriate assignment operator in order to be assign a pointer to a   `DNA` object. Unless you have defined such operator, the assignment is ill-formed.

Comment: While this will help the OP get a valid element, If they try `newDNA [allRightSequences.size() - 1] = NULL;` they are still going to get an error.

Comment: @NathanOliver not necessarily. It is possible to define an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

What you might want (though not sure from the question yet), is an array of pointers to DNA objects.
What you are declaring is "just" an array of DNA objects; and you can't set an object to null, as [Pete Becker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785483/671366) explains very well.

The following code would work:

```
// notice how we use +1 here to have place for the NULL element at the end
DNA* newDNA[] = new DNA*[allRightSequences.size()+1];  
newDNA [allRightSequences.size()] = NULL;
```

For each element of the array, you'd however also have to create a DNA object via `new DNA...` then...

Note that if you use a compiler supporting C++11, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.
And if you want to avoid the hassle with pointers completely, you could use a construct like `std::optional` in case you use C++17 or `boost::optional` for earlier versions, as described in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48454518/671366), as mentioned by Baum mit Augen above.

Also, the good question is what you really need that zero pointer at the end - if it's just for determining the last element when iterating over the array, then you might be better off using an `std::vector<DNS>` or a similar collection type instead...

Comment: Instead of using `newDNA = new DNA*[allRightSequences.size()]; newDNA[allRightSequences.size()-1] = NULL`, consider using `newDNA = new DNA*[allRightSequences.size()+1]; newDNA[allRightSequences.size()] = NULL` instead. This way, `newDNA` contains the same number of accessible elements as `allRightSequences` rather than losing 1 element.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
newDNA [allRightSequences.size()-1] = NULL;
```

Because an array index in C++ goes from `0` to `n-1`, where `allRightSequences.size()` in your case returns `n`, where `n` is the size of the array.

Comment: define operator=() method beacuse when use newDNA [allRightSequences.size()-1] = NULL; compiler find operator=() method which is not defined and throw a error.